# How to read array list object to text file in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to make a method where I can read the text file to the array lists. My ArrayList contains objects, I use some system out println so I can detect where it went wrong, and turns out it's on the while loop part can anyone help me?

```
public class DataIO {
    public static ArrayList<CitizenData> citizenData = new ArrayList<CitizenData>();
    public static ArrayList<AppointmentData> appointment =  new ArrayList<AppointmentData>();
    public static void read(){
        try{
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Citizen.txt"));
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            while(s.hasNext()){
                String fullName = s.nextLine();
                String numberID = s.nextLine();
                int age = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                Date date = formatter.parse(s.nextLine());
                String address = s.nextLine();
                String phoneNum = s.nextLine();
                String email = s.nextLine();
                s.nextLine();
                CitizenData data = new CitizenData(fullName,numberID,age,date,address,phoneNum,email);
                citizenData.add(data);
            }
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Appointment.txt"));
            DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
            while(s.hasNext()){
                CitizenData numberID = DataIO.check(s.nextLine());
                VaccinationCentre vacCentre = VaccinationCentre.valueOf(s.nextLine());
                LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(s.nextLine());
                String vaccineType = s.nextLine();
                s.nextLine();
                AppointmentData data1 = new AppointmentData(numberID, vacCentre, date,vaccineType);
                appointment.add(data1);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in read");
        }
    }
        
       public static void write(){
        try{
            PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("Citizen.txt");
            for(int i=0; i<citizenData.size(); i++){
                p.println(citizenData.get(i).getFullName());
                p.println(citizenData.get(i).getNumber());
                p.println(citizenData.get(i).getAge());
                p.println(citizenData.get(i).getDob());
                p.println(citizenData.get(i).getAddress());
                p.println(citizenData.get(i).getPhoneNum());
                p.println(citizenData.get(i).getEmail());
                p.println();
            }
            p.close();
            PrintWriter q = new PrintWriter("Appointment.txt");
            for(int i=0; i<appointment.size(); i++){
                AppointmentData j = appointment.get(i);
                q.println(j.getNumberID());
                q.println(j.getVaccineCentre());
                q.println(j.getDate());
                q.println(j.getVaccineType());
                q.println();
            }
            q.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in write!");
        }
    }
    
     public static CitizenData check(String x){
            for(CitizenData d : citizenData){
                if(d.equals(d.getNumber())){
                    return d;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

But here every time I run the code, it keeps on going to the catch and it says "error in read". Is my code wrong, but in which part of it?

Comment: `System.out.println("Error in read")`, that's not really useful exception handling, neither for you nor for us. Print the exception stacktrace in your `catch` clause via `e.printStackTrace()` and add the stacktrace to your question. (And also have a look at the exception stacktrace yourself, you might even find out yourself, what went wrong)

Comment: In your `while-loop` your are reading many lines in once. Are you sure your file contains all these lines ? otherwise a `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown

Comment: Also check your file format against the code. Can you include a relevant section of data (be sure it's not real data for real people, obviously, for privacy reasons)?

Comment: wait let me try

Comment: its says that unparsable date but why my date format didn't change when I already use the formatter